# URL Rewrite IIS - Map From One Path To Another

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am playing with URL rewrite in IIS 7

The behaviour I want is when someone types in

[http://localhost/Sales]

they get redirected to [http://localhost/SalesDemo]

but they still see [http://localhost/Sales] in the browser URL

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that would be to use [Rewrite Maps](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module) in URL Rewrite Module.

Alternatively you could add `rewrite` section to your `web.config` file.

`Web.config` example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite rule">
                    <match url="^Sales$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="SalesDemo" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please note that the action type needs to be `Rewrite` (and not `Redirect`) if you still want to see `/Sales` in your browser.

I hope that will help.